# Workflow 4.5 ReceiveAndSendReply

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4, .net-4.5

I have a state machine workflow of 2 states. State 1 has 2 transitions and they share the same trigger, a Receive operation.

What i want to do is:
if the received message is "GO" the transition1 action is to reply "DONE"
if the received message is not "GO" the transition2 action is to reply "TRY AGAIN"

The problem im facing is:
I can use a ReceiveAndSendReply activity, but i cant get everything to work with the receive on the trigger and the reply on the **transitions** Actions...

Can anyone tell me how can i do this?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a give receive message can have more than 1 reply if the correlation is set properly. For more info see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358755.aspx

Comment: Is there actually a way how to drag&drop an additional SendReply shape within the designer and connect it to the same Receive? The only way I was to able to create multiple replies was to play around in the XAMLX file...